# Faster way of searching than nested loops in python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, nested-loops, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find the optimal order for least expected cost for an array.

The input is:

```
input = [[390, 185, 624], [686, 351, 947], [276, 1023, 1024], [199, 148, 250]]
```

This is an array of four choices, the first number being a cost and the second two being the probability of getting the result, the first (`[i][1]`) of which is the numerator and the second (`[i][2]`) is the denominator.

The goal is to find the optimal order of these value/probability pairs that will provide the result at the least total cost.

```
def answer(input):

    from itertools import permutations

    length = len(input)
    best_total = 999
    for combination in permutations(input):
        # print combination
        total = 0.0
        for i in range(0, length):
            current_value = 1.0
            for j in range(0, i):
                current_value = current_value * (1.0 -  \
                (float(combination[j][1]) / float(combination[j][2])))
            total = total + (float(combination[i][0]) * current_value)
            if total > best_total:
                i = length
        # print total
        if total <= best_total:
            best_total = total
            best_combination = combination

    answer = map(input.index, best_combination)

    return answer
```

Running:

```
print answer(input)
```

should return

```
[2, 3, 0, 1]
```

for the given input.

This is obviously an exhaustive search, which becomes very slow very quickly with more than four choices. I've considered binary search trees as the input for those is very similar, however I can't figure out how to implement it.

I've been working on this for four days and can't seem to come up with fast version that works for any input (assuming positive costs and probabilities).

This isn't for homework or anything, just a puzzle I've been trying to figure out.

Comment: where does `minions` come from?

Comment: You should be using xrange for python2, your are building lists every time you call range

Comment: Just a FYI: take a look at the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/fractions.html) module.

Comment: Have tried using numpy? A first step is obviously to find the best algorithm with the lowest complexity. As a next step, you could convert things to numpy, getting a factor 20-50 of speedup is not uncommon for numerical problems.

Comment: You should also `break` `if total >= best_total` inside the outer loop, that alone improves efficiency by over 30 percent on your  input

Comment: I get that the best order is `[2, 1, 3, 0]`. I am missing something?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense at all. I mean, from the explanation, I thought it was trivial? But then your code to solve it is just ridiculous.

Comment: It is not yet clear to me whether this should be a simple sort of (cost, numerator, denominator) on `cost*denominator/numerator`  (i.e. $1 for 1 in 1000 chance should equate to $1000 equivalent)  or `cost*numerator/denominator` or something else.  It is not clear why you need combinations, or whether the tuples represent independent chances to obtain the desired result or are somehow interdependent.

Comment: I don't understand your input data. According to your description, the 3rd option has probability 1023/1024, i.e., almost one. Then how can the others still have so large probability?

Answer (score 1):

I would determine the value of each case in the original array, store these values, and then sort the list. This is in python 3 so I don't know if that affects you.

Determining the value of each case in the original array and storing them:

```
inputA = [[390, 185, 624], [686, 351, 947], [276, 1023, 1024], [199, 148, 250]]
results = []
for idx,val in enumerate(inputA):
    results.append((val[0]*val[1]/val[2], idx))
```

Sorting the list, extracting positions:

```
l = lambda t:t[1]
print(list(map(l,sorted(results,reverse=True))))
```

Iterating over the list is `O(n)`, and the sort is `O(nlogn)`. Map/list/print iterates over it again for `O(n)` so performance should be `O(nlogn)`.